# How to start selenium browser and close it manually?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, selenium, cucumber

I'm using Selenium with Cucumber when testing my rails application. I notice that when starting up the browser there is some sort of delay. Could I just start the browser and never close it? Then the test always run on that browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: No.

I'm not sure this would be desirable either, surely you want your tests to start with a fresh browser instance each time to preserve the exact same environment for them ?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using Spork to speed up your tests.

Look at this to make your own opinion:

http://bddcasts.com/series/tools/episodes/using-spork-to-speed-up-rspec-and-cucumber

Comment: well actually sometimes it is slower to use cucumber with spork comparing to just normal cucumber run http://chrismdp.github.com/2010/11/getting-spork-working-now-on-rails-3-rspec-2-and-cucumber/